# Force field type in telegraf.conf for influxdb?

Tags: time-series, influxdb, telegraf

I am using telegraf to poll some Ubiquiti devices via SNMP. I have the following in my telegraf.conf file to pull in load averages of the devices:

```
  # Load averages
  [[inputs.snmp.field]]
   name = "loadAverage1"
   oid = "UCD-SNMP-MIB::laLoad.1"
  [[inputs.snmp.field]]
   name = "loadAverage5"
   oid = "UCD-SNMP-MIB::laLoad.2"
  [[inputs.snmp.field]]
   name = "loadAverage15"
   oid = "UCD-SNMP-MIB::laLoad.3"
```

This pulls in data which you can see with this query:

```
> SELECT "loadAverage1", "loadAverage5", "loadAverage15" FROM "telegraf_unifi"."autogen"."snmp.UAP" WHERE "agent_host"='192.168.140.100' FILL(null)
name: snmp.UAP
time                loadAverage1 loadAverage5 loadAverage15
----                ------------ ------------ -------------
1553172422000000000 0.14         0.16         0.10
1553172480000000000 0.15         0.16         0.10
1553172540000000000 0.11         0.14         0.10
1553172600000000000 0.23         0.16         0.11
1553172660000000000 0.34         0.21         0.12
1553172720000000000 0.47         0.27         0.15
1553172780000000000 0.26         0.25         0.15
1553172840000000000 0.27         0.26         0.16
1553172900000000000 0.13         0.23         0.16
1553172960000000000 0.08         0.20         0.15
1553173020000000000 0.03         0.16         0.14
1553173080000000000 0.01         0.13         0.13
1553173140000000000 0.06         0.12         0.12
1553173200000000000 0.02         0.09         0.11
1553173260000000000 0.01         0.07         0.10
```

The problem is that these fields are being saved as strings.

```
> show field keys on telegraf_unifi
...
name: snmp.UAP
fieldKey      fieldType
--------      ---------
loadAverage1  string
loadAverage15 string
loadAverage5  string
...
```

Because these are strings, I can't use functions like `mean`.

How can I force these to be saved as float values like my other fields?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is due to the `oid` you are selecting.

Looking at the [UCD-SNMP-MIB](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt) MIB, you can find the `laLoad` object type:

```
laLoad OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX  DisplayString
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS  current
    DESCRIPTION
    "The 1,5 and 15 minute load averages (one per row)."
    ::= { laEntry 3 }
```

This is a `DisplayString`.

It looks like you want the `laLoadFloat` object type.

```
laLoadFloat OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX  Float
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS  current
    DESCRIPTION
    "The 1,5 and 15 minute load averages as an opaquely
     wrapped floating point number."
    ::= { laEntry 6 }
```

Change the `oid` lines in your `telegraf.conf` file to:

```
oid = "UCD-SNMP-MIB::laLoadFloat.1"
```